# So + adj + as to + verb / so +adj + to + verb

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

Can I use those forms interchangeably? I think ***1*** and ***1'*** don't mean the same thing but ***2*** and ***2'*** mean the same thing.

> 1-She was ***so*** radiant ***as to be*** almost beautiful.
>
> 1'-She was ***so*** radiant ***to be*** almost beautiful.
>
> 2-You’re ***so*** clever ***as to solve*** it.
>
> 2'-You’re ***so*** clever ***to solve*** it.

Comment: Now that you've changed 2 and 2', I think 2' sounds better than 2! I am still wondering what your thoughts about the difference between 1 and 1' are; that would help me answer.

Comment: I think 1' is imply a purpose rather than similarity. 1  implies that she was so radiant and she was almost looking beautiful.

Comment: **1'** and **2** are syntactically flawed. **2'** is a *marginally* acceptable reduction from *You’re so clever to **have solved** it*, but as a learner you'd be well advised to avoid it. In short, only **1** is really defensible, and even that one isn't really a good form for a non-native speaker to take to heart, given the vast majority of natives would see it as a bit high-falutin' for a normal conversational context (they'd more likely say something like *She's so radiant **she's** almost beautiful* themselves).

Answer (score 1):

> 1-She was so radiant as to be almost beautiful.

This sounds fine to me. The implication is that she was glowing (radiant) so much that it almost made her appear beautiful. You're right in saying (in your comment) that "so [adjective] as" is used for comparisons.

> 1'-She was so radiant to be almost beautiful.

This sounds weird to me. You say you think this implies a purpose. I get what you're saying - "to be" would mean "in order to be" - but with these particular words it doesn't make sense. If you described something that actually could work as a cause and effect a sentence with this structure would make sense, for example:

> She washed her face to look beautiful.

-

> 2-You’re so clever as to solve it.

This doesn't sound right. *so [adjective] as* can only be used for comparisons, like in sentence 1. It's like saying "so [adjective] that it's like [other thing]". This doesn't work for being clever and solving something. You could say something like:

> You're so clever as to remind me of Einstein.

But that wording sounds stilted. "that" is better here, as in:

> You're so clever that you remind me of Einstein.

Though for most people this would so clearly be an exaggeration that the listener/reader would probably take this to be sarcastic.

> 2'-You’re so clever to solve it.

This is fine. As @FumbleFingers says in their comment,

> '2' is a marginally acceptable reduction from "You’re so clever to have solved it".

I agree with that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not sure why "You’re so clever to solve it." is a reduction from "You’re so clever to have solved it".

Comment: The present perfect tense, "have solved it", is appropriate here because the person ("you") must have solved the problem before the time this sentence is spoken. You can shorten "have solved" to "solve" in casual speech; this is a common thing people do with sentences like this and it will be understood and won't sound strange.

Comment: I didn't read the sentence like that. As far as I understand,  the person is trying to praise the other person("you") by saying this sentence. It is like, you don't even have to solve it. That is so easy for you. This problem or whatever it is, seems so small before you.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden ah, I see what you're thinking. No, that's not a possible meaning in the sentence's form here. "You're so clever as to be able to solve it" - maybe this is what you had in mind. You need "be able to" for this meaning. Still sounds unnatural. I'd prefer something like "You're so clever that I'm sure you could solve it (easily)".

Comment: I am sorry to keep you busy but I am confused big time :) . So when I use "so(with or without so)+adjective+to-infinitive" it means the person have already experienced the situation before saying the sentence. What if I say  "I am so ready to fight" or "Motorcycles are so dangerous to drive"

Comment: No worries! And no, that’s not always true- both your new examples here do not follow that logic. I’m not sure if this is the reason, and not sure I can explain it well, but I think it’s because “ready” and “dangerous” don’t mean much on their own - you have to specify ready *for what* (Answer: to fight) and dangerous *how* (Answer: to drive). “Clever” is understood as a character trait and it cannot be modified with “to” + an infinitive that describes the specifics of the cleverness. But you can say “clever at solving problems”.

Comment: I realize that “dangerous” actually can stand on its own; it has the meaning “unsafe” and that’s fine; you don’t always require additional information with this word. Also, since I believe *to* is a preposition in both your examples, maybe this is just one of those idiosyncracies in English, where the correct preposition is (or at least seems) arbitrary. E.g. “Ready for fighting”- also ok. “Dangerous for driving”- not really ok. “Clever for solving problems”- again, has to mean “clever for having solved problems”.

Comment: Okay last question :), How can I easily understand that usage of "adjective+to-infinitive" is a reduction from "adjective+to-have v3" ?

Comment: I've been thinking about this. Maybe it has more to do with the "extremeness" of the adjective (or adjective phrase), if that makes sense."Clever enough to (infinitive)", "Not clever enough to (infinitive)", "Too clever to (infinitive)", "Sufficiently clever to (infinitive)" - these all work the way you were thinking - they mean "(adjective) such that (infinitive) will (or could) happen". "So clever", "very clever", "really clever", "quite clever" don't work the same way as these other phrases. Maybe because these are less "extreme" descriptions. There's no "threshold" that's been exceeded.

Comment: Then again, if you take that as a rule, there are probably all sorts of exceptions. For example, "I'm happy to solve it" could mean either "I'm happy that I have the opportunity to solve it in the future" or "I'm happy that I have already solved it", depending on the context. English is a weird language!